# Installing/using SASS on Bluehost

Tags: sass, installation, web-hosting, bluehost

Does anyone have experience with using SASS on Bluehost or similar hosting sites.
I'm using putty to get SSH access to the server, and as far as I know Bluehost has already installed SASS(which would explain why the "gem install sass"-command skips the install).
The problem is when I use the "sass --watch someFolder/scss:someFolder/css" it response "-bash: sass: command not found".
If I type "sass -v" it also says "-bash: sass: command not found"
Am I using the wrong commands or do I need to add some file to my directory?
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Try autocompleting the command (ie. sass[tab]) and see what happens.  I've worked with systems that postfix the ruby version onto ruby related commands (ie. running sass would involve using `sass19` since I was using Ruby 1.9).

Comment: Didn't work, but I think it's just putty that doesn't use autocomplete.

Comment: I've found the location of sass: '~/ruby/gems/gems/sass-3.4.7/bin',
if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what the problem was.
Bluehost does have SASS installed by default, but the path didn't work.
You need to add a couple lines to the end of your .bashrc file (it's in the root of your directory)

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/ruby/gems
export GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME:/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.3
export GEM_CACHE=$GEM_HOME/cache
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/ruby/gems/bin
```

Source: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/365